# How to use "adb shell input tap" command in a non-touch screen device

Tags: android, adb, amazon-fire-tv, amazon-fire-os

I use "adb shell input tap 'x' 'y'" command to tap on a specified location on a touch screen android device. But the device I am working on is a TV(based on android) which can only be used using remote.
I am able to enable the pointer location using "adb shell settings put system pointer_location 1" and using bluetooth keyboard connected to the TV found the exact 'x' and 'y' location of the button where i want to tap. But "adb shell input tap" command didn't work as it worked in touch screen device, guess its due to a non-touch screen device.
Is there any workaround to tap the intended button on a non-touch screen (TV) device?

Comment: What does this have to do with amazon-fire-tv or fireos? You didn't mention it in your actual question.

Comment: Use Monkey runner https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796266/5710872

Comment: @Qamar can i get the download link to download the Monkey runner software for my windows 8 PC?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC `shell input tap x y` should work even for the amazon firtev.

But in any case you can just emulate the DPAD actions of the firetv remote with

`adb shell input keyevent <keyeventcode>`

The keyevent codes for the DPAD are

```
19 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_UP" 
20 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN" 
21 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT" 
22 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT" 
23 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER"
```

To emulate the Home and back buttons on the remote use

```
3 -->  "KEYCODE_HOME" 
4 -->  "KEYCODE_BACK"
```

Comment: @joshua could you kindly accept the answer then :)?